# How to Draw Circle in OpenTK Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, opengl, xamarin.forms, opentk

I need to know how to draw transparent circle/ellipse using OpenTK in Xamarin.Forms.

I have tried with creating Vertex and Fragment shaders with reference of following link : [How to draw circle on OpenGL ES 2.0 cross platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729352/how-to-draw-circle-on-opengl-es-2-0-cross-platform)  But did not get anything on screen it is showing blank on screen.

Below is the Sample Code used to draw circle with OpenTK in Xamarin.Forms.

```
        GL.ClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);


        GL.UseProgram(programID);
        // The locations where we pass in our color and vertex data
        positionInput = GL.GetAttribLocation(programID, "Position");
        colorInput = GL.GetAttribLocation(programID, "SourceColor");
        // The locations where we pass in unchanging data
        projectionInput = GL.GetUniformLocation(programID, "Projection");
        modelviewInput = GL.GetUniformLocation(programID, "Modelview");

        Matrix4 modelview = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(rotation) * Matrix4.CreateRotationY(rotation) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(rotation) * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(xTranslation, yTranslation, -7f);
        GL.UniformMatrix4(modelviewInput, false, ref modelview);

        float h = 4.0f * (height / width);
        Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter(-2, 2, -h / 2f, h / 2f, 4, 10);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, (int)width, (int)height);
        GL.UniformMatrix4(projectionInput, false, ref projection);



        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, colorDataBuffer);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(colorInput);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(colorInput, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);


       float DEGREE_TO_RAD = (float)( 3.14 / 180);
        int M_IN_DEGREE = 370;
        int N_IN_DEGREE = 100;
        int nCount = 1;
        int index = 0;
        int size = 2;
        float[] stVertexArray = new float[2*360];

        stVertexArray[0] = 0;
        stVertexArray[1] = 0;

        for( int nR =N_IN_DEGREE; nR < M_IN_DEGREE; nR++ )
        {
            float fX = (float) System.Math.Sin((float)nR * DEGREE_TO_RAD ) ;
            float fY = (float) System.Math.Cos((float)nR * DEGREE_TO_RAD );
            stVertexArray[nCount*2] = fX;
            stVertexArray[nCount*2 + 1] = fY;
            nCount++;
        }
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, stVertexArray.Length);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);


        GL.VertexAttribPointer (index,size, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, stVertexArray.Length, IntPtr.Zero);

        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.LineLoop, stVertexArray.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedByte,stVertexArray);

        GL.Finish();
```

Comment: How are you hooking this up to XF?

Comment: I have used OpenGLView to hook this in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: If you're hoping for an answer you should post a sample project, this is an edge case, I wouldn't expect a lot of people have used it, just looking at a fragment doesn't mean anything. For all I know this code may be perfectly fine but not hooked up properly to the underlying framework. Are you able to draw *anything*? Is it just the circle that's causing you headaches or nothing shows up at all, whatever you've tried