# Could the Accelerate framework on iOS be used to draw a circle?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage, accelerate-framework

I'm trying to write a `GPUImageFilter` subclass that renders potentially thousands of feathered circles (yes, it's a brush stroke). My current approach comprises a `glDrawArrays` call that draws a tonne of squares, and a vertex attribute for each that informs the fragment shader where the centroid for each is, so that the shader can draw a circle whose alpha values taper out toward the edge (farthest from the centroid).

This is plenty fast on my test device (an iPad Mini) unless there are (a) more than 1,000 circles or (b) the circles are really big. The polys are fast, but the shader slows down pretty quickly.

I'm wondering if it would be faster to render the circles directly to a byte buffer, and have GPUImage (using `GPUImageRawDataInput`) grab the bytes whenever it can for rendering (via other filters) to the screen.

The Accelerate framework is the fastest way I know how to manipulate bytes on iOS. I've found that I can for example very quickly fill an RGBA buffer with vDSP using this method:

```
const int iValue = [RGBA colour as int];

vDSP_vfilli(&iValue, (int*)bytes, 1, width * height);
```

Can anyone suggest how I might use either the `vDSP` or `vImage` function sets to render feathered circles into my byte buffer? The only ways that spring to mind involve far too many `for` loops to be performant.

Answer (score 3):

For drawing many feathered circles, you might not find a better way than using many quads and a fragment shader. The performance problem you seem to have here is the need to blend together an arbitrary number of overlapping circular elements in a single frame. Not only do you have a large number of parallel pixels to process, you have a large number of possible circles that could be affecting each pixel.

I faced a similar problem in my Molecules application, and asked about tuning my shaders for that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051237/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-my-custom-opengl-es-2-0-depth-texture-gener). In the case of Molecules, I'm drawing hard-edged sphere impostors, but I still needed to blend together thousands of them, or ones of a very large size.

There are some immediate things you can do to improve performance in your fragment shader (unfortunately, without the code that you're using, I can only guess if you're doing this). First, remove branching if you have that in your shader. Use `step()` (most likely `smoothstep()` in your case) to replace if statements. Second, shift whatever calculations you can to your vertex shader. The vertex shader only runs once per vertex for your quad, as opposed to your fragment shader running once per pixel. I passed in a normalized -1,-1 to 1,1 coordinate for each of the four vertices, which made it simpler to calculate a distance from a center point in my fragment shader.

Disabling blending greatly speeds up rendering on these devices, but I don't think you're going to be able to do that here. You might be able to do something clever with the new-in-iOS 6 framebuffer fetch operations to improve blending performance, but I'm not sure if that would help either.

By far the biggest performance win will come from trying to reduce the amount of drawing you need to do. In my case, I was able to draw a series of opaque squares (octagons in the final iteration) behind where my sphere impostors would be, and use the depth buffer to throw out pixels that would never be visible in any conditions. That led to something like a 6X performance improvement. If some portion of your circles was opaque, you might be able to do a prepass like this.

Given that this is a brush stroke, though, it seems to me that you should be able to do a simpler optimization in that you only draw anything that's changed from frame to frame. Older versions of your drawn brush image could be stored into a flat texture that is only drawn on with the new brush strokes (and saved again as the stored texture). You shouldn't need to redraw all brush strokes for each frame, and this should reduce your render load significantly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this with vImage, but nothing intended to do just that -- it doesn't do vector graphics -- so you are probably better off turning the buffer into a CGbitmapContext and using CG to draw circles into it, or use various approaches like those already suggested by Brad Larson.

Anyway, for completeness, if all the circles are the same size and color, you could draw one circle, then repeatedly composite it into place with one of the alpha blending functions in vImage/Alpha.h.   I suppose vImageDilate would expand a bright point on a black field to an arbitrary shape, including circles, but this is likely to be expensive, potentially very expensive. It gives you a bit more control over color, though. Likewise various convolutions could blur bright points out in a circular pattern. I would be very surprised if any of these methods, except perhaps the alpha method is faster than CG.