# Can an OpenGL ES fragment shader change the depth value of a fragment?

Tags: c, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Can fragment shader in OpenGL ES 2.0 change the Z value (depth) of a pixel?

How is this achieved in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: See also: [Writing texture data onto depth buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534467/writing-texture-data-onto-depth-buffer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No -- `gl_FragDepth` (which is part of the desktop version of GLSL) is not present in OpenGL ES.

You can, however, check for the existence of `GL_EXT_frag_depth`. If it's available, then you can write the depth to `gl_FragDepthEXT`.

The [extension paper](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_frag_depth.txt) gives more details about how to enable the extension and such.

Comment: Does anyone have a list of hardware that supports GL_EXT_frag_depth?

Answer (score 0):

While `gl_fragDepth` is not available in OpenGL ES 2.0, is is [available from version 3.0 onwards](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml), so upgrading would be the way to go unless you need to use the older version for compatibility.